# Inject at same time a service and provider in angular configuration

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular configuration:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("app.functionality")
        .config(config);

    //  +------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //  |   Implementations                                                |
    //  +------------------------------------------------------------------+
    config.$inject = ["$stateProvider"];

    function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("aState", {
                url: "/:idf/:idc",
                views: {...},
                resolve: {
                    aPromise: function ($stateParams) {
                        return {
                            idf: $stateParams.idf,
                        };
                    }
                },
            });
    }
})();
```

and elsewhere:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("MyService", [])
        .factory("myService", service);

    service.$inject = ["$http"];

    function service($http)
    {
        // implementations
    }
})();
```

This works pretty well and I can get `idf` value. What I really want is:

- handle different state (I can do it easily with $stateProvider)
- use resolve function to return a richer state-based data

This richer set of data should be retrieved trough a service (right after the `idf` property)

```
richerSetOfData: aService.getSomething($stateParams.idf)
```

But alas I know that I can't inject service into `config` (just provider). I could use `run`, but run doesn't fit well with provider (and I need $stateProvider). So how can I do what I need? And what the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can inject service in resolve function:

```
       resolve: {
            aPromise: ['$stateParams', 'myService', function ($stateParams, myService) {
                return {
                    idf: myService.doSmthng($stateParams.idf)
                };
            }]
        },
```

Comment: I have no erro but as soon I inject that service into resolve function. The template in `templateUrl` is not rendered anymore.

Comment: State controller and service placed in different modules. Make shure that modules are loaded correctly.
`.module("app.functionality", ['MyService'])`